# How to use group by with intersect command in TSQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, relational-database

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM members AS t1
INNER JOIN data AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE members_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM members AS t1
INNER JOIN data AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE members_id = 2
```

I would like to use the group by and order by commands like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), var1
FROM members AS t1
INNER JOIN data AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE members_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT COUNT(*), var1
FROM members AS t1
INNER JOIN data AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE members_id = 2
GROUP BY var1
ORDER BY var1
```

However, I get thrown an error saying var1 is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Any tips on using GROUP BY and ORDER BY with the intersect command?

Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion - please put code/sql fiddle to create a sample table and insert some sample rows. It makes it easy for people to test their answers and help you. Chenqui.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the query you are trying to achieve?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), var1
FROM members AS t1 INNER JOIN
     data AS t2
     ON t1.ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY var1
having sum(case when members_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end)  > 0 and
       sum(case when members_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end)  > 0 ;
```

This gets the count for each `var1` that has both members.

Comment: Adding a group by to the top select would eliminate the error message, however, Gordon's approach is much cleaner.

Comment: @JiggsJedi . . . Adding a `group by` to the original query would eliminate the error message.  And it would probably eliminate the results as well.  Intersect looks at both columns, so the count would have to be the same as well.